# How to get Gradle build version in index.html or in javascript

Tags: javascript, gradle, gruntjs

I have gradle build for my project, some of the details defined in project.ext section of build.gradle file.

```
project.ext {
  myVar1 = "Var1";
  myVar2 = "Var2";
  .....
}
```

Is there any way I can access those variables using grunt or anything to use in html file or in javascript?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it but only through filtering - not directly - see [this](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#renameOnCopy) part of gradle docs. Basically filtering is done while copying artifacts to other destination.

Comment: @SomeUIDev, was the answer useful?